# How do I buy weapon attachments in Splinter Cell Blacklist?

Tags: splinter-cell-blacklist

For example, I bought sniper rifle in splinter cell blacklist. A menu on the right says "Upgrades 0/4" or something like that. I would like to buy these upgrades but I cannot figure out - how?

If I click on the weapon in the left menu, nothing happens. 
If I navigate on it with my arrow keys and then press enter - nothing happens either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify your weapons, go to the Armory area of Paladin. At the end of the room, you'll see a prompt to hit "[Space] Customize Gear".

[image]

When in this menu, edit the loadout for "Campaign - Sam Fisher", navigate to the weapon in question, and then click on the Spanner icon next to the weapon name.

[image]

This should allow you to customize your weapon by purchasing (and equipping) attachments and upgrades.

[image]